# Laptop wont show wifi connections

Tags: 16.04, wireless, laptop

I just finished installing Ubuntu 16.04.05 (Desktop) LTS on an acer Aspire 3690 laptop. This OS works just fine on this laptop, however I'll see the wifi symbol on top, but it wont recognize any wifi signal. Ethernet works just fine, issue is only with wifi. Is there any way I can get the laptop to recognize wifi signals?

```
06:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. TravelMate 2410 [1468:0312]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: And what is Ubuntu 16?

Comment: @Pilot6 my apologies

Comment: You need `firmware-b43-installer`. `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer` will fix it, if you are connected by Ethernet.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you very much, the issue has been resolved. Cheers